# how to change vertical spacing via css on word wrap?

Tags: css

My first question here. I have a  tag which wrap words that are too long for its space. Which is alright, but I want to reduce the vertical spacing between the rows. Is it possible doing this by css?

Comment: Can you add your HTML please, I can't really understand your situation. What tag ? What rows ?

Comment: Did you tried line-height?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly your case but i think this will help you. Is taken from w3schools

Imagine you have a paragraph like this in html:

```
<p class="small">
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a smaller line-height.<br>
</p>
```

You add a class for the `<p>` tag and then in the css:

```
.small {
    line-height: 70%;
}
```

Yo can use a percentage or a value in pixels. You can also use this class for other tags.

Yo also can see an this example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height)